# CIFS VFS: Server X has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

```
CIFS VFS: Server X has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
...
```

This message is spamming my `dmesg` output. The warning is caused by the following mount of a windows share:

```
# CIFS shares
//X/share/folder        /mnt/some_folder      cifs          vers=2.1,credentials,uid=some_user,gid=some_user,file_mode=0764,dir_mode=0765,nosetuids,noserverino  0 0
```

The share works. From various posts I consulted, it seems this warning is normal. Any way to suppress it (if it's normal after all), or adjust the parameters so it doesn't show?